# typing arrows in plain text?

Tags: text

In plain text (as opened in emacs, gedit, ...), how can I type up and down arrows?
I type the up arrow in two lines, as "^" above "|", where aligning them is very inconvenient. I don't know how to type down arrow.

I typed left arrow as "<-" and right arrow as "->". Is it the best way we can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Type arrows by copy/pasting the Unicode characters in the first column of the below table.

You can also type an HTML entity in the third column and it will render as the appropriate arrow character.

You can also press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> keyboard combination which will print a `u` character on the screen. Then after the `u` type one of the 4-digit hexadecimal codes in the second column and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to render the u+4-digit hexadecimal number that appears on the screen as the appropriate arrow character.

| Character | Hex | HTML Entity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ← | 2190 | &larr; |
| ↑ | 2191 | &uarr; |
| → | 2192 | &rarr; |
| ↓ | 2193 | &darr; |
| ↔ | 2194 | &harr; |
| ↕ | 2195 | &varr; |
| ↖ | 2196 | &nwarr; |
| ↗ | 2197 | &nearr; |
| ↘ | 2198 | &searr; |
| ↙ | 2199 | &swarr; |

HTML entities for mdash and ndash (for long dashes) are &mdash; and &ndash;
HTML entities for less than and greater than characters are &lt; and &gt;

Comment: how are they typed directly without copying and paste?

Comment: The keyboard character codes are: `&uarr; &darr; &larr; &rarr;`

Comment: How do the keyboard character codes work? Isn't that HTML?

Comment: w3schools.com calls them HTML entities. I prefer to use HTML entities for typing arrows because they're so easy to remember. For example in the HTML entity `&larr;` `&` is the HTML entity beginning character, `;` is the HTML entity end character, `l` is short for left and `arr` is short for arrow. Just type the HTML entity instead of copy/pasting the corresponding arrow character. Both ways show the same character in a web browser.

Comment: @karel OK, but how do you insert them into a plaintext file?

Comment: For composing offline I use an markdown editor application from the default Ubuntu repositories called ReText which is similar to gedit. Clicking the *Preview* button in the ReText toolbar displays all of the typed text in markdown formatting and displays the corresponding HTML entity arrow text as arrows.

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, then type the hexcode of the character, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Hex codes for arrows:

| Symbol | Hex Code |
| --- | --- |
| ← | 2190 |
| ↑ | 2191 |
| → | 2192 |
| ↓ | 2193 |
| ↔ | 2194 |
| ↕ | 2195 |
| ↖ | 2196 |
| ↗ | 2197 |
| ↘ | 2198 |
| ↙ | 2199 |

Comment: press enter after that ;)

Comment: what are the hexcode of the characters? You mean the code under UTF8? In what editor, gedit, emacs, ...?

Comment: hexcode of up arrow is 2191.